# Url rewriting only directories

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Currently my root web directory has a .htaccess which redirects to my application folder like such:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$   app/    [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/$1  [L]
</IfModule>
```

And inside the /app directory I have another .htaccess which has the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]

</IfModule>
```

At this point, back in my PHP, I can use $_GET['url'] to obtain the requested URL. This is all fine and good. However, what I am looking to do, is only have it rewrite if the requested url is a directory, and if the requested url is to a file, it will actually redirect to that file for viewing. I am not sure if this can be done purely through the .htaccess, or if there is a way in php to do a `is_file` check, and then do a header redirect to the file?

Right now if I do a `is_file` check, and do a header redirect, I get placed in a loop, because the htaccess in the webroot obviously wants to redirect to the /app directory

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: 1) What URL is giving you the trouble? 2) Where that folder **physically** located (inside `app` folder .. or outside -- e.g. inside website root)?

Comment: if I try to go to testdomain.com/test.php, it will just redirect me inside the app folder, to the index in there.

Comment: Sorry -- but I do not understand what problem you are having here. Your title says "Url rewriting only directories" .. but you are giving URL that is a PHP file ... Can you please formulate your question more clearly -- 1) what needs to be done in general, 2) how it works right now (apparently wrong, as I understand) and 3) how it should work instead.

Comment: It's just as I said: I only want the url rewrite to happen when the requested url is a directory. Otherwise it should go to the file requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not 100% clear on what exactly is required, hopefully this is what you are asking. If not -- let me know.

Add one more rule into website root .htaccess to tell Apache to ignore requests to existing files:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # do not rewrite requests to existing files
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule . - [L]

    RewriteRule ^$ app/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.+) app/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Obviously, if file was requested (e.g. `example.com/test.php`) but it does not exist, the rewrite will still occur.

Comment: This is already being done in the .htaccess inside the app folder, but it looks like the OP wants to be able to reference files (if they exist) outside of app, so the rule in his second htaccess is no good ;) But yep, this is how to do it.